# Talend Parallelization and Java Scope

Tags: java, mongodb, talend

I am creating a job to create a complex multi level document for mongoDB from relational data.

I read 'product' records in from Oracle.

I have a tJavaRow and I use the mongoDB API to create a product document (BasicDBObject) using the product details coming in.  I store this document in the global map (call this 'product_doc')..as I need to embed a sub-document in this later in the sub job.

I use a tFlowToIterate to store the product_id in the globalMap.

I then have another Oracle input which uses the product_id from the global map as a parameter in the sql, so getting the many part of the relationship to products (call this 'product_orders').

I build a java List of 'product_order' documents and write the List to the globalMap, let's call this 'product_orders'.

I then insert the 'product_documents' List as a sub document to the 'product' document in a tJava component. And I write 'product' to mongoDB and then I move on to the next product row from Oracle.

It is more complex than this, creating a 5 level hierarchy...but this s the basic idea - but it takes 3 hours to run.

So,I want to set the job to run parallelized, so each product row from Oracle gets despatched onto a new thread...Round Robin style.

However, I have a heavy dependency on the globalMap to store objects for later use in the flow....and I know the threads will trample all over each other.  I assume each thread maintains the same variable scope across the sub job...

I can identify the thread_id using a global variable in the globalMap "tCollector_1_THREAD_ID" I think.

So I had considered doing this when I add documents/objects into the globalMap.

globalMap.put("product_doc_" + globalMap.get("
tCollector_1_THREAD_ID"))

So that everything I put in the globalMap is thread specific and tagged...but I don't know how tCollector_1_THREAD_ID gets populated, if it is in the globalMap then surely each thread can trample over this value also?

It didn't work...I was getting a load of Null Errors.

So I guess my question is about variable scope and use of globalMap when using tJavaRow components in a parallelized data flow, when you need to maintain references in each thread.

---- UPDATE ------

For clarity if you look at this page it states you can get the thread ID from the variable tCollector_1_Thread_ID.  BUt it gets that variable from the globalMap.

Surely the globalMap is a global variable so how can the multiple threads not be all changing this global variable all the time and interfering with each other?

https://help.talend.com//pages/viewpage.action?pageId=265114338

Comment: This is a long question, so I just ran over it.

If you use the enterprise version, just click on the Iterate link, and there should be an "Enable parallel execution" checkbox. Enable it, and forget partitioner/collector. globalMap is thread safe, it will be created for each and every thread you use along with the thread. So you can use the globalMap.get("myVarThatWasCreatedOutsideOfTheThread") safely. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, I was trying to read the code behind the job, and struggled a lot - but I did see code which seemed to indicate it was creating separate globalMaps per thread.  So each thread has access to its own globalMap, but share access to variables created in the subJob scope?  I guess you still have to be careful with object references in the separate globalMaps pointing to the same objects?  I struggle to understand if all my variables created in tJavaRow in each individual thread after tPartitioner, share scope at all - as they would if I wasn't using parallelization.

Comment: I usually created single thread programs. Then multi-threaded them by using that Enable parallel execution. And it works fine, unless you want to pass the globalMap parameters back to the caller thread. That I haven't done.

Comment: And you are using tJava and tJavaRow in the same sub-job as the departitioner?  I am sure it works, just want to understand as I am creating variables in tJavaRow and referencing them later in the thread, and I dont want each thread trampling all over each others globalMaps or variables...I am sure this doesnt happen ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few approaches that I am using successfully for parallel executions:

If possible create another job that you run parallel, that helps understanding the tasks:
[image: Using Iterate links]

In this example I use the "Use or Register a shared Db connection" feature, so I re-use my connections. tJavaFlex just contains a simple try{ } catch block, so I handle / hide the errors.
GpOutput uses a connection that was created outside of the threads.

[image]

I more prefer this approach where I create a separate job and use the context parameters to pass information to the job.
[image]

Here you can see how the globalMap is used.

I found that the tPartition/Departitioner in talend is very hard to use. I prefer to use more controlled ways to handle parallel executions. Such as a Loop that splits the workload on 20 parallel threads.

```
  " WHERE mod(num,20) = " + context.i "
```

Comment: Thanks, how are you spawning threads at your will if not using the parallelize components? I like the idea of tRunJob as I am more convinced things are running in separate scopes.